# how to make the floating label in the Right

Tags: android, android-edittext

how can i make the floating label appears in the right side of my EditText
here is my MaterialEditText Class
Im sure that i should change in this line:

```
// draw the floating label
            canvas.drawText(getHint().toString(), getPaddingLeft() + getScrollX(), position, paint);
```

but how???

here is my code:

```
    public class MaterialEditText extends EditText {
    public static final int FLOATING_LABEL_NONE = 0;
    public static final int FLOATING_LABEL_NORMAL = 1;
    public static final int FLOATING_LABEL_HIGHLIGHT = 2;

    /**
     * the spacing between the main text and the inner top padding.
     */
    private int extraPaddingTop;

    /**
     * the spacing between the main text and the inner bottom padding.
     */
    private int extraPaddingBottom;

    /**
     * the floating label's text size.
     */
    private final int floatingLabelTextSize;

    /**
     * the spacing between the main text and the inner components (floating label, bottom ellipsis, characters counter).
     */
    private final int innerComponentsSpacing;

    /**
     * whether the floating label should be shown. default is false.
     */
    private boolean floatingLabelEnabled;

    /**
     * whether to highlight the floating label's text color when focused (with the main color). default is true.
     */
    private boolean highlightFloatingLabel;

    /**
     * the base color of the line and the texts. default is black.
     */
    private int baseColor;

    /**
     * inner top padding
     */
    private int innerPaddingTop;

    /**
     * inner bottom padding
     */
    private int innerPaddingBottom;

    /**
     * the underline's highlight color, and the highlight color of the floating label if app:highlightFloatingLabel is set true in the xml. default is black(when app:darkTheme is false) or white(when app:darkTheme is true)
     */
    private int primaryColor;

    /**
     * the color for when something is wrong.(e.g. exceeding max characters)
     */
    private int errorColor;

    /**
     * characters count limit. 0 means no limit. default is 0. NOTE: the character counter will increase the View's height.
     */
    private int maxCharacters;

    /**
     * whether to show the bottom ellipsis in singleLine mode. default is false. NOTE: the bottom ellipsis will increase the View's height.
     */
    private boolean singleLineEllipsis;

    /**
     * bottom ellipsis's height
     */
    private final int bottomEllipsisSize;

    /**
     * animation fraction of the floating label (0 as totally hidden).
     */
    private float floatingLabelFraction;

    /**
     * whether the floating label is being shown.
     */
    private boolean floatingLabelShown;

    /**
     * the floating label's focusFraction
     */
    private float focusFraction;

    private ArgbEvaluator focusEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    ObjectAnimator labelAnimator;
    ObjectAnimator labelFocusAnimator;
    OnFocusChangeListener interFocusChangeListener;
    OnFocusChangeListener outerFocusChangeListener;

    public MaterialEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MaterialEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public MaterialEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
        super(context, attrs, style);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setClickable(true);

        floatingLabelTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.floating_label_text_size);
        innerComponentsSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.inner_components_spacing);
        bottomEllipsisSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_ellipsis_height);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaterialEditText);
        baseColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_baseColor, Color.BLACK);
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][] {new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, EMPTY_STATE_SET}, new int[] {baseColor & 0x00ffffff | 0xdf000000, baseColor & 0x00ffffff | 0x44000000});
        setTextColor(colorStateList);

        primaryColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_primaryColor, baseColor);
        setFloatingLabelInternal(typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_floatingLabel, 0));
        errorColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_errorColor, Color.parseColor("#e7492E"));
        maxCharacters = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_maxCharacters, 0);
        singleLineEllipsis = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_singleLineEllipsis, false);
        typedArray.recycle();

//      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//          setBackground(null);
//      } else {
//          setBackgroundDrawable(null);
//      }
        setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        if (singleLineEllipsis) {
            TransformationMethod transformationMethod = getTransformationMethod();
            setSingleLine();
            setTransformationMethod(transformationMethod);
        }
        initPadding();
        initText();
        initFloatingLabel();
    }

    private void initText() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())) {
            CharSequence text = getText();
            setText(null);
            setHintTextColor(baseColor & 0x00ffffff | 0x44000000);
            setText(text);
            floatingLabelFraction = 1;
            floatingLabelShown = true;
        } else {
            setHintTextColor(baseColor & 0x00ffffff | 0x44000000);
        }
    }

    private float getFloatingLabelFraction() {
        return floatingLabelFraction;
    }

    private void setFloatingLabelFraction(float floatingLabelFraction) {
        this.floatingLabelFraction = floatingLabelFraction;
        invalidate();
    }

    private float getFocusFraction() {
        return focusFraction;
    }

    private void setFocusFraction(float focusFraction) {
        this.focusFraction = focusFraction;
        invalidate();
    }

    private int getPixel(int dp) {
        return Density.dp2px(getContext(), dp);
    }

    private void initPadding() {
        extraPaddingTop = floatingLabelEnabled ? floatingLabelTextSize + innerComponentsSpacing : innerComponentsSpacing;
        extraPaddingBottom = maxCharacters > 0 ? floatingLabelTextSize : singleLineEllipsis ? innerComponentsSpacing + bottomEllipsisSize : 0;
        extraPaddingBottom += innerComponentsSpacing * 2;
        setPaddings(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
    }

    /**
     * use {@link #setPaddings(int, int, int, int)} instead, or the paddingTop and the paddingBottom may be set incorrectly.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Override
    public final void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    /**
     * Use this method instead of {@link #setPadding(int, int, int, int)} to automatically set the paddingTop and the paddingBottom correctly.
     */
    public void setPaddings(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        innerPaddingTop = top;
        innerPaddingBottom = bottom;
        super.setPadding(left, top + extraPaddingTop, right, bottom + extraPaddingBottom);
    }

    /**
     * get inner top padding, not the real paddingTop
     */
    public int getInnerPaddingTop() {
        return innerPaddingTop;
    }

    /**
     * get inner bottom padding, not the real paddingBottom
     */
    public int getInnerPaddingBottom() {
        return innerPaddingBottom;
    }

    private void initFloatingLabel() {
        if (floatingLabelEnabled) {
            // observe the text changing
            addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        if (floatingLabelShown) {
                            floatingLabelShown = false;
                            getLabelAnimator().reverse();
                        }
                    } else if (!floatingLabelShown) {
                        floatingLabelShown = true;
                        if (getLabelAnimator().isStarted()) {
                            getLabelAnimator().reverse();
                        } else {
                            getLabelAnimator().start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            if (highlightFloatingLabel) {
                // observe the focus state to animate the floating label's text color appropriately
                interFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            if (getLabelFocusAnimator().isStarted()) {
                                getLabelFocusAnimator().reverse();
                            } else {
                                getLabelFocusAnimator().start();
                            }
                        } else {
                            getLabelFocusAnimator().reverse();
                        }
                        if (outerFocusChangeListener != null) {
                            outerFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus);
                        }
                    }
                };
                super.setOnFocusChangeListener(interFocusChangeListener);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setBaseColor(int color) {
        baseColor = color;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setPrimaryColor(int color) {
        primaryColor = color;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    private void setFloatingLabelInternal(int mode) {
        switch (mode) {
            case FLOATING_LABEL_NORMAL:
                floatingLabelEnabled = true;
                highlightFloatingLabel = false;
                break;
            case FLOATING_LABEL_HIGHLIGHT:
                floatingLabelEnabled = true;
                highlightFloatingLabel = true;
                break;
            default:
                floatingLabelEnabled = false;
                highlightFloatingLabel = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setFloatingLabel(int mode) {
        setFloatingLabelInternal(mode);
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setSingleLineEllipsis() {
        setSingleLineEllipsis(true);
    }

    public void setSingleLineEllipsis(boolean enabled) {
        singleLineEllipsis = enabled;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public int getMaxCharacters() {
        return maxCharacters;
    }

    public void setMaxCharacters(int max) {
        maxCharacters = max;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setErrorColor(int color) {
        errorColor = color;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener listener) {
        if (interFocusChangeListener == null) {
            super.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
        } else {
            outerFocusChangeListener = listener;
        }
    }

    private ObjectAnimator getLabelAnimator() {
        if (labelAnimator == null) {
            labelAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "floatingLabelFraction", 0f, 1f);
        }
        return labelAnimator;
    }

    private ObjectAnimator getLabelFocusAnimator() {
        if (labelFocusAnimator == null) {
            labelFocusAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "focusFraction", 0f, 1f);
        }
        return labelFocusAnimator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // set the textSize
        paint.setTextSize(floatingLabelTextSize);
        Typeface mfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/AraHamahAlHorra-Regular.ttf");
        paint.setTypeface(mfont);
        // draw the background
        float lineStartY = getScrollY() + getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() + innerComponentsSpacing;
        if (!isEnabled()) { // disabled
            paint.setColor(baseColor & 0x00ffffff | 0x44000000);
            float interval = getPixel(1);
            for (float startX = 0; startX < getWidth(); startX += interval * 3) {
                canvas.drawRect(getScrollX() + startX, lineStartY, getScrollX() + startX + interval, lineStartY + getPixel(1), paint);
            }
        } else if (hasFocus()) { // focused
            if (isExceedingMaxCharacters()) {
                paint.setColor(errorColor);
            } else {
                paint.setColor(primaryColor);
            }
            canvas.drawRect(getScrollX(), lineStartY, getWidth() + getScrollX(), lineStartY + getPixel(2), paint);

            // draw the characters counter
            if (maxCharacters > 0) {
                if (!isExceedingMaxCharacters()) {
                    paint.setColor(getCurrentHintTextColor());
                }
                Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = paint.getFontMetrics();
                float relativeHeight = -fontMetrics.ascent - fontMetrics.descent;
                String text = getText().length() + " / " + maxCharacters;
                canvas.drawText(text, getWidth() + getScrollX() - paint.measureText(text), lineStartY + innerComponentsSpacing + relativeHeight, paint);
            }
        } else { // normal
            paint.setColor(baseColor);
            canvas.drawRect(getScrollX(), lineStartY, getWidth() + getScrollX(), lineStartY + getPixel(1), paint);
        }

        // draw the floating label
        if (floatingLabelEnabled && !TextUtils.isEmpty(getHint())) {
            // calculate the text color
            paint.setColor((Integer) focusEvaluator.evaluate(focusFraction, getCurrentHintTextColor(), primaryColor));

            // calculate the vertical position
            int start = innerPaddingTop + floatingLabelTextSize + innerComponentsSpacing;
            int distance = innerComponentsSpacing;
            int position = (int) (start - distance * floatingLabelFraction);

            // calculate the alpha
            int alpha = (int) (floatingLabelFraction * 0xff * (0.74f * focusFraction + 0.26f));
            paint.setAlpha(alpha);

            // draw the floating label
            canvas.drawText(getHint().toString(), getPaddingLeft() + getScrollX(), position, paint);
        }

        // draw the bottom ellipsis
        if (hasFocus() && singleLineEllipsis && getScrollX() != 0) {
            paint.setColor(primaryColor);
            float startY = lineStartY + innerComponentsSpacing;
            canvas.drawCircle(bottomEllipsisSize / 2 + getScrollX(), startY + bottomEllipsisSize / 2, bottomEllipsisSize / 2, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(bottomEllipsisSize * 5 / 2 + getScrollX(), startY + bottomEllipsisSize / 2, bottomEllipsisSize / 2, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(bottomEllipsisSize * 9 / 2 + getScrollX(), startY + bottomEllipsisSize / 2, bottomEllipsisSize / 2, paint);
        }

        // draw the original things
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public boolean isExceedingMaxCharacters() {
        return maxCharacters > 0 && getText() != null && maxCharacters < getText().length();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (singleLineEllipsis && getScrollX() > 0 && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getX() < getPixel(4 * 5) && event.getY() > getHeight() - extraPaddingBottom - innerPaddingBottom && event.getY() < getHeight() - innerPaddingBottom) {
            setSelection(0);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

and called in layout like this:

```
<net.urengwuxian.materialeditlibrary.MaterialEditText
                    android:id="@+id/number_trade_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/number_trade_text_hint"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:baseColor="@android:color/black"
                    app:floatingLabel="highlight"
                    app:maxCharacters="5"
                    app:primaryColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```